# MVC Controller Return Content vs Return Json Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

In MVC, why does returning `Content` sometimes fail in the Ajax callback, while returning Json works, even for simple string objects?

Even when it fails, the data is still available if you were to access it in the always callback...

### Update:

When I set the contentType in the ajax call to `text/xml` the response will no longer enter the error message.

### AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "/MyController/GetFooString",
    data: { },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("Ajax Failed!!!");
    }
}); // end ajax call
```

### Controller Action That Fails (Sometimes)

*Even when it fails, the data is still available.*

```
public ActionResult GetFooString()
{
    String Foo = "This is my foo string.";
    return Content(Foo);
} // end GetFooString
```

### Controller Action That Always Works

```
public ActionResult GetFooString()
{
    String Foo = "This is my foo string.";
    return Json(Foo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
} // end GetFooString
```

Comment: Define "fails."  What is the actual response returned from the server and how does it differ from a "successful" response?

Comment: It enters the error function in the Ajax method even though the data is returned correctly, and without any errors.  Successful response is triggered in the Ajax Success method, where I alert data.

Comment: Try adding contentType: "application/json", to your parameters list.

Comment: @silencedmessage: In order for there to be any difference in the handler, *something* about the response must be different.  Its content, its headers, something.

Comment: @David Returning content doesn't fail if I change the content-type to `text/xml` in the Ajax call.  A coworker had a theory that Content returns a string object that is translated as plain text, whereas returning json explicitly returns a json object.

Comment: @Scottie I did have that, accidentally sliced it out of my question though.  Updated!

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `ContentResult` instead of `ActionResult`?

Comment: Or even better, `JsonResult`.

Comment: @MelanciaUK I was previously told that it is ok to return an ActionResult when returning either ContentResult or JsonResult, as they are both acceptable return types for an [ActionResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult.aspx). Is it a better practice to explicitly specify?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `Content(Foo);` sends a response that doesn't have the mime type header. This happens because you're not setting `ContentType` when using this overload. When the Content-Type is not set, jQuery will try to **guess** the content type. When that happens, whether it can successfully guess or not depends on the actual content and underlying browser. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))

`Json(...)` on the other hand [explicitly](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/ASP.NET-Mvc-3/blob/master/mvc3/src/SystemWebMvc/Mvc/JsonResult.cs#L49) sets the content type to `"application/json"` so jQuery knows exactly what to treat the content as.

You can get consistent result from `Content` if you use the [2nd overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492713(v=vs.118).aspx) and specify a ContentType:

```
return Content(Foo, "application/json"); // or "application/xml" if you're sending XML
```

But if you're always dealing with JSON, then prefer using `JsonResult`

```
return Json(Foo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: +1. But if the OP will always expect JSON, wouldn't be better to just change `ActionResult` to `JsonResult`?

Comment: @MelanciaUK: If one always expects JSON, then yes. But I see your point. Updating my answer...

Comment: In *this* case, I would always be expecting JSON, but the part that I was truly missing was the mime type and the differences between `ContentResult` and `JsonResult`.